# How to extract css values from website page

Tags: javascript, python, css, web-scraping

Is there any way to extract css values from website page using css class name. I want to get all css values and child class values using parent class css name.

For an Example:

Wepage Css :

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .btn-wrap {
    padding: 3px;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .text-box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .frm-btn-grp {
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

  .btn-success {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 7px 24px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
  }
  }
```

If i will give **.frm-btn-grp** as input It will return

```
.frm-btn-grp {
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

  .btn-success {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 7px 24px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
   }
  }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: More curiosity than anything... why are you doing this?

Comment: @roganjosh Now i want to extract all css values by manually.It will take more times.So i will  looking some automation code.Is it possible?

Comment: That reiterates _what_ you want to do, but I asked _why_.

Comment: @Bryan I didn't start anything. I had searched related this but still i have no idea how to start this idea.That's why i  posted this question.

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://tinycss2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#parsing

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299005/scraping-css-values-using-scrapy-framework

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do this using Python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501268/beautifulsoup-get-css-classes-from-html

Answer (score 1):

Here's some webscraping action:

```
import re
import urllib.request as ureq

sample_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685137/how-to-extract-css-values-from-website-page"

with ureq.urlopen(sample_url) as req:
    data = req.read().decode('utf-8')

#- Split HTML by line ending; Look for 'text/css' matches
css_lines = [i.strip() for i in data.split('\n') if len(i) > 0 and 'text/css' in i]

#-- Create a simple regular expression to extract the css html
#-- Note: ?P<named_tag> allows for naming each section, but I think
#-- it only works on compiled regular expresions, which isn't a huge
#-- deal.
css_pat = r'href="(?P<css_url>.+)"'
p = re.compile(css_pat)

#-- Create a list and append it with our matches.
css_urls = []
for i in css_lines:
    tmp = p.search(i).group('css_url')
    if tmp:
        css_urls.append(tmp)
```

Output:

```
In[4]: css_urls
Out[4]: 
['https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=d0797a2dd6f2',
 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=f7becef1b212']
```

Then, you can do whatever. Iterate the urls to get all of the css data, open and join all the css files into one, etc.

```
with ureq.urlopen(css_urls[0]) as req:
    css_data = req.read().decode('utf-8')

#-- Here's a sample printout of a css file for this page
#-- I added some .replace() statments to make it prettier :-)
print(css_data[:500]
    .replace(',', ',\n')
    .replace('{', ' {\n\t')
    .replace(';', ';\n\t')
    .replace('}','\n\t}\n\n')
    )
```

Truncated output:

```
html,
body,
div,
span,
{...}
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
        font:inherit;
        font-size:100%;
        vertical-align:baseline
        }

article,
a
```